# how can i write java output in text file continuously

Tags: java

I tried to get the output of java program as a text file.but when i print output in a text file and for the next set of input it overwrites on it.I want to see all of my output in an order in a text file.How can I?

Comment: Append your output to the file. Show us the code you use to write to file.

Comment: Kindly write your code will make us much better to understand the problem

Comment: If you are using a fileWriter, pass in `true`, `new FileWriter(filename,true)`

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in this question to answer it. Are you talking about command line redirection or Java file i/o?  Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using `FileWriter` , pass true as a second argument to FileWriter to turn on "append" mode.

```
fout = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);
```

[FileWriter usage reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

Comment: thanks a lot its work done.but when we pass false as a second argument to FileWriter to turn off "append" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a `FileWriter`, you can provide `true` as the second parameter to the [`FileWriter(java.io.File, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) or [`FileWriter(java.lang.String, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)constructor, to indicate that you wish to append to the file, rather than overwriting.

It may be more efficient, however, to append everything to a `StringBuilder`/`StringBuffer` beforehand, and only write once.

Comment: when we pass false as a second argument to FileWriter to turn off "append" mode.we must pass true as the second parameter.this is the correct code for the above problem.                                `fout = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);`

Comment: Sorry?  I've indicated that you should provide `true` as the second parameter if you want to append rather than overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

can't do match without a code, but when you writing to the file you must keep a variable that remembers the location of a last character you wrote, so whenever you start writing your continuous output you will provide the location from where to start writing

Comment: This is certainly one way to do it but it is by far not the best. The accepted answer is the best solution.